# MySQL sort table by 2 columns of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I thought this would be easy, but I don't find a solution:

I have a very large table with items that have a "name" column.

I have a second table with corresponding "localized name" for some of the items of table 1.

I now want table 1 ordered by "localized name" from table 2, but if no localized name exists ordered by "name" from table 1.

Example:

Table 1

```
id name
1  USA
2  Italy
3  Germany
4  Australia
```

Table 2

```
id loc_name    t1_id
1  Italia      2
2  Deutschland 3
```

Result

```
4 Australia
3 Deutschland
2 Italia
1 USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.loc_name, t1.name) as real_name
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.ti_id
order by coalesce(t2.loc_name, t1.name);
```